# Receive Single Url from Json Arrays

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I receive an array of URLs from JSON request

This my code

```
 if let slideShow = self.json["graphql"]["shortcode_media"]["edge_sidecar_to_children"]["edges"][].array {
     for allMedia in slideShow {
         let medias = allMedia["node"]["display_resources"][2]["src"].stringValue
         print("All Media \(medias)")
     }
 }
```

I want to show the user a preview of every image, so I need each of these URLs individually. How I can get a single URL from this array?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You posted code that dives deep into an object graph that comes from JSON and fetches an array `slideShow` and then loops through the `slideShow` array, diving into **that** for a URL. You appear to be successfully finding the URLs that you want. What problem are you asking for help solving?

Comment: Sorry for the not very exact question. I need each of these urls individually. How can I get them from an array?

Comment: The code you posted already does that. What else do you need to do with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create var array of strings, then append a new url string to it inside for loop:

```
var medias = [String]()

if let slideShow = self.json["graphql"]["shortcode_media"]["edge_sidecar_to_children"]["edges"][].array {
     for allMedia in slideShow {
          medias.append(allMedia["node"]["display_resources"][2]["src"].stringValue)
     }
     print("All Media \(medias)")
}
```